# java looping program cant detect symbols

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have a little issue with this program I am writing. When I run this with CMD it gives me a few errors such as the variable "totalFry" cant be defined even though it is a Global Variable. Any Help would be great, thank you very much! 
(Note: this is my first time writing looping/ while code)

- The idea is to give the user 3 choices, have the user input an option
  (1-3) and have said options appear to prompt the user to input the
  amount they want for said team.
- Next, the program will ask the user
  if they want to end the order, assuming they input "Yes" the program
  will ask if the user wants to end the program if the user inputs
  "yes" the program will go and total up the cost and display it.
- End of program

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner; 

//Lab 4_5
public class Lab4_5 {
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Declare local variables
    static double totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda;
    static int option, burgerCount, fryCount, sodaCount;

    // The main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Add a loop to run program again
        String endProgram = "no";
        while (endProgram.equals("no"))

            //Add a loop to take in order
            String endOrder = "no";
        while (endOrder.equals("no"))

            // Add statements to display the menu, get the user choice, and assign it to option
            System.out.println("Enter 1 for Yum Yum Burger");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 for Grease Yum Fires");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 for Soda Yum");

        //Add a Select Case statement based on the value of option
        int option = 0;
        option = keyboardnextInt();

        //When option = 1
        if (option == 1)
            double totalBurger = 0;
        int burgerCount = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of burgers you want ");
        burgerCount = keyboard.nextDouble();
        totalBurger = totalBurger + burgerCount * .99;
        //When option = 2
        if (option == 2)
            double totalFry = 0;
        int fryCount = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of fires you want ");
        fryCount = keyboard.nextDouble();
        totalFry = totalFry + fryCount * .79;
        //When option = 3
        if (option == 3)
            double totalSoda = 0;
        int sodaCount = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of sodas you want ");
        sodaCount = keyboardnext.Double();
        totalSoda = totalSoda + sodaCount * 1.09;

        //Imput if user wants to end order
        System.out.println("Do you want to end your order? (Enter no to add more items ) ");
        endOrder = keyboard.next();

        //Call
        clacTotal();
        printReceipt();

        //Ask user if they want to end the program
        System.out.println("Do you want to end the program? (Enter no to process a new order) ");
        endProgram = keyboard.next();
    }

    //Calculate the total amount
    public static void calcTotal() {
        double total = 0;
        double tax = 0;
        double subtotal = 0;
        //Add statements to calc total with tax and call printReceipt
        calcTotal = totalBurger + totalFry + totalSoda * .06;
    }

    public static void printReceipt() {
        //Add statements to display the total as shown above
        System.out.println("Your total is $" + calcTotal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly so we can understand it easily. I assume there are some '{' and '}' missing (around the while bodies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has many issues including the following:

1. missing curly braces on beginning and end of `if's` and `loops`
2. creating duplicate variables.
3. using keyboard.nextDouble() on ints

plus some spelling mistakes.

The following code should at least compile and work as you wanted.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4_5 {
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

// Declare local variables
static double totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, calcTotal;
static int option, burgerCount, fryCount, sodaCount;

// The main method
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Add a loop to run program again
    String endProgram = "no";
    while (endProgram.equals("no")){

        //Add a loop to take in order
        String endOrder = "no";
        while (endOrder.equals("no")){

        // Add statements to display the menu, get the user choice, and assign it to option
            System.out.println("Enter 1 for Yum Yum Burger");
            System.out.println("Enter 2 for Grease Yum Fires");
            System.out.println("Enter 3 for Soda Yum");

            //Add a Select Case statement based on the value of option
            int option = 0;
            option = keyboard.nextInt();

            //When option = 1
            if (option == 1){
                totalBurger = 0;
                burgerCount = 0;
                System.out.println("Enter the number of burgers you want ");
                burgerCount = keyboard.nextInt();
                totalBurger = totalBurger + burgerCount * .99;
            }   
            //When option = 2
            if (option == 2){
                System.out.println("Enter the number of fires you want ");
                fryCount = keyboard.nextInt();
                totalFry = totalFry + fryCount * .79;
            }   
            //When option = 3
            if (option == 3){
                System.out.println("Enter the number of sodas you want ");
                sodaCount = keyboard.nextInt();
                totalSoda = totalSoda + sodaCount * 1.09;
            }   

            //Imput if user wants to end order
            System.out.println("Do you want to end your order? (Enter no to add more items ) ");
            endOrder = keyboard.next();
       }

        calcTotal();
        printReceipt();

      //Ask user if they want to end the program
        System.out.println("Do you want to end the program? (Enter no to process a new order) ");
        endProgram = keyboard.next();
    }
}

  //Calculate the total amount
  public static void calcTotal() {

      //Add statements to calc total with tax and call printReceipt
      calcTotal = totalBurger + totalFry + totalSoda * .06;
  }

 public static void printReceipt() {
    //Add statements to display the total as shown above
    System.out.println("Your total is $" + calcTotal);
  }
}
```